# abstract reacting to exit code

Tags: bash, exit-code

I have a script where I repeatedly want to react to the exit status of a command like this (this is a simplified form):

```
function f() {
command1 $x $y && echo OK || return 1

#...

commandN $z $t && echo OK || return 1
}
```

Is there a simple way to abstract this away?
I was thinking of something along the lines of

```
function runme(){
  $@ && echo OK || return 1
}


function f(){
  runme command1 $x $y 
  #...

}
```

but of course the `return` just applies to the `runme` function itself, and
doesn't return from `f`.
I also couldn't get 'set -e' to [work as I expected in all cases](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Is there a simple way to abstract this `if-else` away with pure bash?

Comment: Don't use `a && b || c` when what you want is `if a; then b; else c; fi`. They're not 100% identical, and the corner case (where `a` succeeds but `b` fails, so `c` gets run instead) can mess you up.

Comment: Also, `$@` and `"$@"` are not the same. **Always** use the quotes, or you get behavior identical to (unquoted) `$*`.

Comment: Also, `function f() { ... }` is merging the POSIX syntax `f() { ... }` and the legacy ksh syntax `function f { ... }` in a way that isn't compatible with *either* POSIX sh _or_ legacy ksh. Unless you have a _very_ good reason to do otherwise, leave the `function` keyword out and just use POSIX declaration syntax.

Comment: @KamilCuk I  want to return 1, that is, interrupt the current function, not the whole script

Comment: BTW, I strongly recommend reading [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (at least the exercises section, if you haven't the time/patience for the allegory) before deciding to consider using `set -e`.

Comment: Do you *want* to run a command like `runme`, or would something like `command1 "$x" "$y"; check || return 1` be ok?

Comment: I'm thinking of a hack involving history expansion: `command! "$x" "$y"; !42`, where 42 is the history entry populated by `history -s '&& check || return 1'`.

Comment: @chepner I want some simpler solution, and that with `check`  looks like a lot like what I already have in place

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm aware of the issues with `set -e` (linked in the question) so I want to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Don't `return 1` -- just `return`; that way you pass through the *specific* exit status of the command that failed, instead of collapsing all possible failed exit codes down to always be exactly `1`.

Beyond that -- if you want to write clear, explicit, portable code, you'll end up making the `return`s explicit. Thus:

```
# return with no arguments uses "$?", which will be the exit status of "$@"
runAndAck() { if "$@"; then echo "OK"; else return; fi; }

f() {
  runAndAck command1 "$x" "$y" || return
  runAndAck command2 "$z" "$t" || return
}
```

...otherwise you end up dealing with the myriad of differences between how individual shells (and versions of the same shell -- different bash releases vary) implement `set -e`.